# How do you make an effective Minecraft mob trap?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Alright, so what's the best way to go about making a good mob trap in Minecraft? Here are some traits I'd like to have in the trap:

1. Easy to build.

   Although I have (or can easily obtain) whatever materials needed for a mob trap, I'd prefer it to be simple, as I have a talent for melting myself in lava, falling down extremely deep pits, and other unfortunate accidents.
2. Completely reliable.

   Preferably, once I build this trap, I'd like it to be mob-proof, with no chance of 3 spiders clogging the trap for an hour. Additionally (although this isn't quite so important), it would be nice for there to be an escape route, in case I accidentally fall into the trap myself.
3. Good item-gathering.

   Self-explanatory. I want the trap to gather all of the items (losing string I don't care about, but I want to collect all the useful drops like gunpowder and arrows), and deposit them via water/whatever method works at a nice drop-off point outside the trap.

So, given these three preferred qualities, what would be some good traps for me to build?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I highly recommend Etho's excellent subterranean spawning pads with a water-based mobevator for moving mobs to the surface. An ammended tutorial for the mob-spawner and transporter can be found [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f8YJfAwYOz0).

The video doesn't include a mob-killing mechanism but there are multiple examples on his youtube channel. Personally I prefer transporting them a bit to the side of the mobevator, then leading them up a 2x2x4 tube of water with signs creating a gap one tile up from the ground. The mobs swim to the top and drown in the enclosed 2x2x2 cube of water, while their drops fall through the gap and into the bottom 2x2x1 water stream that you can channel wherever you want to.

[Edit: I forgot to address your requirements.]

Easy to build?
It requires nothing but pickaxes and a bucket.
Glass makes it easier to construct but isn't necessary.

Completely reliable?
I have never seen a clog, ever, nor has it ever failed to kill a mob.

Good item-gathering?
100% recovered drops, no lava or cacti to destroy them and you can channel them to a single tile anywhere you want with the output water stream.

Comment: Awesome. This is the one I'm going to try to build.

Comment: Just a quick update, the mobavator works perfectly, although slowly (as I haven't cleared out a lot of cave systems). Just add a grinder, and you have an excellent mob trap.

Answer (score 6):

My favourite mob trap by far is [this record-farming one](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LW0Vt4eO3AM&feature=feedlik). It's based on standard trap principles that you've no doubt read about on the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Traps) and elsewhere, and will collect all the standard mob drops such as string/arrows/bones etc. I love it for the simple fact that it shows that with enough ingenuity, anything is possible in Minecraft!

Answer (score 4):

Go to [Here](http://www.minecraftforum.net/viewtopic.php?f=1020&t=149865#Automatic%20Methods)

I recommend the one called "Practical Monster Trap for SMP-PVP" for getting started on the in and outs, but there are a lot more on the list.

Answer (score 3):

I'm building [this one](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZyQ34XdkbsE). It doesn't require any lava, just water, signs, glass, and a stone half-block. It even includes a monster-proof escape hatch in case you fall in. No monster drops get lost or burned. They are all collectible standing in one spot. And as shown in the video it works on all monsters as well as passive animals (even chickens).

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you build the trap underground. This is easier than having to build a really tall tower (and risk falling yourself). Dig a really deep hole and at the top of it build a large room that is 2 blocks high. Make sure it's large and has no windows or torches. 
The only tricky part about this is being able to co-ordinate the place where the monsters fall and the opening where you are going to collect the goodies.

This trap will kill 100% of all the mobs as long as you dig the hole deep enough. You can even add some cactus to the bottom of your shaft/hole to make sure that the mobs are dead.
This trap also works on minecraft pocket edition.

Answer (score 2):

Try using gravity to help. Build a big shaft with a large room at the top with no light in it. At the bottom of the shaft, put a door to collect all goods. It is easy to build, with any material that does not fall, and reliable if you made the shaft high enough. To gather goods all you need to do is open the door and collect the items. If the monster is still alive, it will be weak and only needs a few hits to finish it off.

How it works: The monsters spawn in the room on top of the shaft. The monsters wander around a bit and fall into the shaft. The monsters die of fall damage and you collect the goodies.

Comment: As for the new mob behavior update mobs dont wander into holes more then 2 deep. Your method will still work though if mobs get pushed into the hole (by for example pistons or water.)

Answer (score 2):

I know a few traps - one is to have a stream of water interrupted by 1 or more cacti. Any mobs caught in the stream will (hopefully) die or at least be reduced to 1 heart or maybe 2. If they die, their drops will flow towards the end, where you can get them. Another one if good but only works for zombies & skeletons. Dig a cross - each 'arm' must be 8 blocks long from the central point - with the centre dug 3 blocks down. Put a chest (ender if you can't access it) on the bottom, and then a hopper. The mobs will flow towards it and burn, their drops going into the chest. (And yes, you CAN still open a chest if a hopper is above it.

Comment: Also, even though I already know an endermen farm, but its REALLY tall and almost impossible to build!

Comment: I decided to build one on the roof of my house with a large chest next to it, both chests in line with each other and it.

Answer (score 2):

I have found a lava blade to be very effective.  Using a spawner design from someone else with triangular spawning pads and timed water releases to flush them into the lava blade and the drops are collected in a 1 block wide water stream.

I have also modified this to use a checkerboard pattern of stones, alternating the spaces for each layer so that the mobs will only drop 2 blocks each time they fall, and the mobs will spawn and fall through into the water on their own.  Thus reducing the need for redstone.  A few 3x3 pads will produce spiders in the spawner.  This design does not collect from enderman because of the water.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite simple but requires a lot of bricks.
First, build tall walls around the side of a spawner, but the square must be big, put torches in so you can see what you are doing at night!
Then dig a long starcase but it must fit in the trap, and then dig up until you are back in the open.
 Then, build an overhanging roof that doesn't go on top, up a few blocks above.
This is so they don't burn in the sun!
Then go out of you trap and dig a tunnel into where the pit drop is and this will be where you retrive your items. Remember to then take out your torches!
But leave them in the tunnel or else monsters will join you in there!
This is something I have used many times it has never failed me!

Answer (score -3):

here is a nice way to get goodies from creepers,zombies etc. if you r on survival mode you will need alot of materials such as any block of ur choice and and water. build up until you cant go anymore and then mine a couple of blocks down and then make a large dark box  put some torches around so u can c wat u r doing then put water in the corners and then take back the torches and fall down the spawner and then wait for mobs to come down and then they die then take their goodies such as if its a creeper its gunpowder,enderman, enderpearl,skeleton bones arrows enjoy!!!!!